# Unable to get posted data with Angular from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I'm sending a post request to my asp.net server from angular and i tried printing the values of my custom model class (**SchoolModel**) and it's all the values corrent inside angular. But when i try to get these values on asp.net it doesn't return anything from inside the object. Please help me if i'm missing something.

**My angular code request**

```
const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', };
            const body = { schoolData };
            this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/CreateSchool", body, { headers }).subscribe(response => {
            
                console.log(response);
                
    
            }, error => console.error(error));
```

**My ASP.NET code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Api/CreateSchool")]
    public bool CreateNewSchool(SchoolModel schoolData)
    {
        bool schoolCreated = false;
        // IT PRINTS SCHOOL NAME ONLY 
        Console.WriteLine("SCHOOL NAME " + schoolData.Name);
        return schoolCreated;
    }
```

Comment: What's `schoolData` in angular code? If it is a Json object did you try sending it in the request instead of sending body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use JSON.stringify(body) to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Use FromBody attribute.

public bool CreateNewSchool([FromBody]SchoolModel schoolData)
{

Comment: It would be even more helpful to expand on why using such an attribute solves the problem, ideally with a link to documentation

Comment: This does not solve my problem...